# Alternative to switch statement in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, switch-statement

I am doing a project in which I am loading a table view with JSON data from an asynchronous connection. I am using a `switch` statement to load each row, like so:

```
dictionaryData = [responseString JSONValue]; 
switch (indexPath.row) 
{ 
    case 0: 
    { 
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@ %@",@"Name",[dictionaryData      valueForKey:@"firstName"],[dictionaryData valueForKey:@"lastName"]]; 
        cell.textLabel.text = name;
        break; 
    }
    case 1: 
    { 
        NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",@"Email",[dictionaryData   valueForKey:@"email"]]; 
        cell.textLabel.text = email; } 
        break;
```

There are 8 rows and i have to write 8 switch cases , which i think makes my method too long.
Can anyone tell me that is there any alternative to switch statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases an *object* would be a better alternative.

**Update**

I detailed how one might approach this (in an overengineered manner) here:
[What alternatives to a switch statement could I use to update my UITableViewCells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102700/replace-switch-statement-in-the-code/8103247#8103247)

Comment: It’s the same user posting duplicate questions. It’s also a duplicate of ‘another’ user’s question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090251/substitute-to-switch-statement-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3):

Replace your switch with an array. Each index in the array will correspond to one of the former `case`s. The array should be set up with the keys that you need

```
keyArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name", @"Email", ..., nil];

dictionaryData = [responseString JSONValue];

NSString * rowKey = [keyArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[[cell textLabel] setText:[dictionaryData objectForKey:rowKey]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to `switch` is to use a series of `if`/`else` statements, which doesn't make the code any shorter. If your method is too long or too complex, move the body of each case into its own method, and then just call that method from its corresponding case.

Comment: One of us has misunderstood the question, but I don't know which. :)

Comment: Actually every switch case is of 2-3 lines, so is it ok to have separate 8 methods rather than having it in one method. What you suggest , will it be better as i already have 10-12 lines of code in my method without switch? i guess it will make program more portable!

Comment: @iDev, there's nothing wrong with a switch that has 8 cases at a few lines each. Josh Caswell's solution is also a fine one if you're doing the same thing to different data for each case.